# finding branches of trees with igraph

Tags: r, igraph

Newbie here, so any help appreciated!

I have a weighted tree graph whose branches interest me. Can I use `igraph` to easily find branches (i.e. their edges and vertices) off a given path? Suppose I have a diameter path

```
E(mg, path = diam)
```

and branches off that path. Can I find branches, do stats with their weights, interrogate their associations with other things etc.?

Thanks a lot!

zo

Reproducible example:

```
library(igraph)

g <-erdos.renyi.game(50, 3/50)
mg <- minimum.spanning.tree(g)
diam <- get.diameter(mg)
E(mg)$color = "black"
E(mg, path = diam)$color = "purple"
E(mg, path = diam)$width = 6
```

So the question is: how do I extract the branches off the purple line within igraph? I'd like extract the branches off of the purple path and keep them in a data frame or some other object.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample input data and desired output.

Comment: I don't know if my editing of the original post alerts you to any change or my response to your response does, in any case I've tried to be more clear, sorry for not being so originally. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. There are no weights in your example. You already have gotten the edges in order to color them with `E(mg, path = diam)`. So what exactly do you need that you can't get in this example?

Comment: Sorry, ignore the weights comment. What I want is a data frame or some other object which contains the branches coming off the purple diameter path. I can easily get the complement of the purple line, but I want the branches separately and I'm wondering if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the set of edges that are incidental to the vertices along the purple line but bo not include the purple line, you can get use

```
EL <- difference( E(mg)[inc(diam)], E(mg, path = diam) )
```

We take the different between the all the edges that contain a point in `diam` and remove those edges that lie along `diam`. We can update the graph to make those edges blue

```
E(mg)[EL]$color<-"blue"
E(mg)[EL]$width<-6

plot(mg)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer. How could I get all the rest of the edges along the branches and then distinguish the branches from each other? I.e., for the branch 1-32-24-7 I construct yellow edges, for the branch 23-19-18, I construct red edges, and so on exhaustively, and then I keep the red, yellow, etc. branches

Comment: I cannot find documentation on `from` or `to`, i.e. `E(mg)[ from(EL)]$color = "yellow"` should color branches yellow?

Comment: Let me add a possibly useful rephrasing of the question: how do I first find all the points not on purple path? How do I perform that set complement?

Comment: Comments are not the right place to add new important information to question or ask a new question. It would have been helpful to have this more explicit description in the original question. If you change the question from what you originally asked, you should just open a new question.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Flick, still learning how to use this. I posted a new question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987043/finding-edge-sequences-and-nodes-of-branches-in-igraph