# finding edge sequences (and nodes) of branches in igraph

Tags: igraph

I would like to use igraph to find edge sequences corresponding to branches from a tree. Ideally, I would like to retain the branches in a data frame.

Consider this example:

```
library(igraph)

g <-erdos.renyi.game(50, 3/50)
mg <- minimum.spanning.tree(g)
diam <- get.diameter(mg)
E(mg)$color = "black"
E(mg, path = diam)$color = "purple"
E(mg, path = diam)$width = 6
plot(mg)
```

Here the main path is `diam`, the purple line. Mr. Flick already kindly answered how to find the edges which are incident on `diam` but not within `diam`:

```
EL <- difference( E(mg)[inc(diam)], E(mg, path = diam) )
E(mg)[EL]$color<-"blue"
E(mg)[EL]$width<-6

plot(mg)
```

One may call these the branch "stubs", i.e. the first edge of each branch. The question now is how do I find the **entire** edge sequence of each individual branch.

I have a feeling it is with iterators using `nei` and `inc` following Mr. Flick's intuition, but can't see a way so far.

Example of branches:

[diameter path with branch stubs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2vMN.png)

In the image, the branches would be the (undirected) edge sequences

23-19-18

23-14

23-26

1-32-24-7

1-11-42-35-41

1-11-42-35-9-17

1-11-30-38

1-28

1-33-34

1-33-29

1-48-47

1-48-12

27-49-39

27-6-45

27-6-10

31-20

16-4

Comment: Can you give an example? What do you mean by a branch?

Comment: example added. Hopefully it's clearer now, let me know

Comment: I see. I guess you just need to calculate all shortest paths from all non-diameter vertices to all diameter vertices, and choose the shortest one for all non-diameter vertices.

Comment: Thank you Gabor. You mean longest one, right? Still learning these functions so any example step would be really helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: I thought you wanted the shortest one. E.g. on your plot, you don't want 18-19-23-1-...-21, but the shortest one: 18-19-23.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was confused since I want the longest edge sequence on a branch, i.e. from the end of the branch to the diameter path, e.g.the full branch 23-19-18 and not just the branch stub 23-19. Any hints on how to find just the non-isolated vertices not on diam?

Comment: hey Gabor, I'd love your thoughts on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022788/optimizing-branch-path-detection-basic-set-operations-in-igraph